# Thread safety of single line in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, one-liner

Since I'm implementing for the first time a quite complex multi-threaded application in java, I was wondering about thread safety on data structures. Obviously my first goal is to achieve thread safety but I would like also to achieve a good performance avoiding useless extra locks. The hypothesis is that I'm not using concurrent/thread-safe alter ego of the used DSs (I'm going to use DS as "data structure" from now on).

My general approach is this one:

When the same data structure is used for more than one line or there's an iteration on it in the same method/code block I'm going to synchronize that block on the DS. Even if it's a read only block. For example this code:

```
synchronized (networkView) {
    for (int othersID : networkView.keySet()) {
        networkView.get(othersID).send(new CloseConnectionMessage(ID));
        networkView.get(othersID).close();
        networkView.get(othersID).join();
    }
}
```

Where `networkView` is a classic HashMap. This is because while I'm working (iterating/reading multiple times) on that DS I don't want anyone to write it externally. Now every time I'm writing `networkView` I'm going to synchronize that block even if it's a one-liner to avoid concurrent modification like this other example:

```
public void clearNetwork() {
    synchronized (networkView) {
        networkView.clear();
    }
}
```

And here's the first question: is it also necessary to synchronize on one-liners that only read the structure? For example if a method returns the lenght of this data structure, is it thread safe without a synchronized block? like this one:

```
public int getNetworkView() {
    return networkView.size();
}
```

So the underlying question is: single line of codes are thread safe or not? As I said before modification one-liners should anyway be synchronized because they should not interfere with mutliple read blocks (like the first example) but can they also interfere with one-liner reads and write? If example 2 and 3 methods are executed concurrently, is it thread safe?

Another question is this one: with DS used only with one-liners I would say it's enough to use their thread-safe counterparts (like ConcurrentHashMap), while they're not enough in a case like the first example without the synchronized block. Am I right about this?

Comment: Explain “concurrent/thread-safe alter ego of the used DSs”. And what is “DS”?

Comment: @BasilBourque: I thought he refers to the Distributed Systems = DS, better to clarify like you said :)

Comment: @BasilBourque I'm referring to Data Structure. And with the final s is just obviously the plural. I'm gonna make it clear by editing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the underlying question is: single line of codes are thread safe or not?

That really isn't how it works. Interactions are 'safe' or 'unsafe'; single lines are not individually so.

However, in general the rule: It's never safe.

If you fail to synchronize on a `.size()` call, that may return a size that is wildly wrong. Here's the simple rule:

- If a field, of any object, is being accessed by 2 or more threads, at least one of which is writing it, **that code is broken**.

The only way it isn't broken is if you take care to write a so-called Happens-Before relationship across **all** such accesses. An HB relationship is a thing described in the Java Memory Model documentation that establishes the following notion:

- If line A has a happens-before relationship relative to line B, then when B executes, it is not possible to observe state as it was *before* A finished execution.

That's all you get.

Thus, if you fail to establish HB, The JVM is free to feed you state that has long since passed on. However, the JVM is not **obligated** either - the JMM is the one place in the java documentation where the term 'may' shows up a ton. That's because java has to run on many, many platforms and they just don't behave the same in regards to on-core caches and other such hardware concerns. In order to ensure a JVM can run code speedily instead of having to slow everything down to a crawl with e.g. global interpreter locks the way python and co have to do it, the JMM instead claims sizable swaths of "the JVM is free to do this thing, or not do this thing - it is on you, the coder, to ensure this 'I may or may not do that thing' does not affect the output of your program".

To establish HB, there are a few strategies:

- "Natural": Within one thread, obvious lexical rules. Given: `foo(); bar();` in a single method, foo() is HB relative to bar(). This one is the obvious one.
- Thread starting. `thread.start();` is HB relative to the first line that thread's `run()`.
- `synchronized`. The line exiting a sync block is HB relative to any entering of a sync block, so long as these sync blocks are syncing on the same object of course.
- access to a `volatile` field, but note that it tends to be difficult to know which line was HB and which one is HA, with `volatilez`.

There are a few more, but those are the basics.

Thus, here you want the last time this object is modified by some thread to be HB relative to invoking `size()`, because otherwise `size()` might as well be telling you what the size() was 18 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

> while I'm working (iterating/reading multiple times) on that DS I don't want anyone to write it externally.

May I suggest a different way of thinking about `synchronized`? In most programs, we deal with *structured* data. At a low-level we have general-purpose, reusable structures such as your `HashMap`, and at higher levels we have structures that are narrowly specified to meet the needs of a specific application.

It frequently is impossible for any single thread to update data without *temporarily* putting some structure into an invalid or inconsistent state. This is because the thread can only update the data piece-by-piece. It cannot *atomically* make all of the changes in a single instant. So, if a structure is shared by two or more threads, then how can any thread make a change without the risk of letting some other thread see the structure as inconsistent/invalid?

The `synchronized` keyword rescues us. If we make sure that every thread that updates *or even just looks at* a certain structure only ever does it from inside a block that is `synchronized` on some certain object, O,* then we can create the *illusion* (as seen by threads B, C, D, E, and F) that the changes made by thread A happened atomically (I.e., all in a single instant.)

---

* For best results, declare the variable that refers to object, O, as `final`, and put it somewhere close to the declarations of the variables that refer to the data it protects.  E.g., If the data are members of some class, then you might declare `final Object lock=new Object()` in that class. Or, if the data are `static` members, then you'd have `static final Object lock=new Object()`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've read it carefully and as a result I think you're basically saying that one-liners are not safe most of the time and also the reading ones should be synchronized. The thing I've understood less is about using an external Object as a lock. I know it's used (I've tried it myself) but in this case why is it wrong/is it worse locking on the data structure itself?